# python regex matching between two strings

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

I have the following string:

```
property some_property_name;
    @(posedge some_clock) disable iff (some_other_signal)
    signalA &&  signalB || !($isunknown(some_other_signal)) &&
    |->  !($isunknown(should_not_match_this))
endproperty

more_random_code

property some_other_property_name;
    @(posedge some_clock) disable iff (some_other_signal)
    signalA &&  signalB || \*!($isunknown(dont_match_if_commented_out))*\ &&
    more_random_stuff ||
    random_stuff
    |->  some_other_expression
endproperty

property next_property_name;
    @(posedge some_clock) disable iff (some_other_signal)
    signalA &&  signalB || !($isunknown(some_other_signal)) &&
    |->  some_other_expression && expressions_etc
endproperty
```

I want to match !($isunknown(.*)) that is between "@(posedge" and "|->". the regular expression I tried is:

```
(?<=@\(posedge ) ([^*]!\(\$isunknown\(.*\)[^*]) (?=(.*\n.*)*\|->)
```

but it does not match anything and i dont see why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use something like

```
(?<=@\(posedge).*?(\!\(\$isunknown\(.*?\)\)).*?\|->
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/S5hvPO6L2aUjLsUN)

with the [re.DOTALL](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) flag so that your `.` expressions include line breaks.

Comment: that worked , thanks a lot ! and that debuggex is a really usefull site.

Comment: just noticed that if the "!($isunknown(some_other_signal))" on line 3 is removed then it does match "!($isunknown(should_not_match_this))" on line 4 after the |->, is there a way to prevent that ?